# how to add to a post to a user ID through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i attach a user to a post through the rails console, I forgot the correct way of doing so. So lets say you created a post and wanted to attach it to the user_id that you created how would i do so through  rails console.

---

Rails console

```
@post = Post.create(content: "nice day we are having")

@user = User.find(2)
```

Comment: what is you association? `user has_many  posts`?

Comment: `User.find(2).posts.create(content:'text')` use this

Comment: you should use @user.posts.create(content: "nice day we are having"), it will add the user_id in post record.

Comment: @titan no like if i was to attach a post through the rails console, i think it would be something like this post.user =user_id(2), i don't think that right but something like that. Basically i want to create a post in the console then attach the user_id to that post through the console

Comment: @power thank you!!

Comment: you should also share the model associations in the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating post individually, you can create it via @user like this:

```
@user = User.find(2)
@user.posts.create(content: "nice day we are having")
```

It will automatically assign the user_id to the post record.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `has_many` association between `User` and `Post` like `user has_many posts' then in console you can attach them as:

```
@user.posts << @post
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple steps:**

*Create a new post:*

```
p = Post.new
p.title = "post title"
p.body = "post body"
```

*Find user to be attached to post*

```
 u = User.find(2)
 p.user_id = u.id
 p.save
```

**This works well**

**OR TRY THIS**

```
u = User.find(2)
p = u.posts.build("title"=> "post title", "body" => "post body")
p.save
```

This method needs relationship to be defined before you can run command in console.

Answer (score 1):

If there are many posts, then it will be cost effective to run a loop to append the user IDs to all posts at once. One way to do it in the console is:

```
everyevery = Post.all #Assign all posts to a variable
```

Then iterate through and append IDs:

```
everyevery.each do |post|
   if post.user_id = nil
      post.user_id = 1 # Assigns user_id of 1. If there are 5 then you could do say rand(1..5)
      post.save
   end
end
```

Of course, this assumes you already have your `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationships in place

Answer (score 0):

First, check you have association between User and Post than in console simply write:

```
@post = Post.create(content: "nice day we are having", user: User.find(2))
```